# How can I get a reference of a pending intent after its execution

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am currently trying to make an alarm app using android studio and I am having trouble making the dismiss alarm button.

I am passing the request code of the pending intent, when it is created, to my Alarm class which has inherited the Broadcast Reciever which is again sending the request code to a new activity Alarm Page where you can dismiss the Alarm. And using this request code I am creating a pending intent and I am trying to cancel the alarm using this pending intent as it should be the same pending intent I have created(they have the same request code)

```
boolean result=databaseHelper.addAlarm(fh+":"+fm); 
int requestCode=databaseHelper.returnLastId();
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Alarm.class);
i.putExtra("rc",requestCode);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),requestCode,i,0);             alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
```

```
int id=intent.getIntExtra("rc",-1);
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);
mediaPlayer.start();
Intent intent1=new Intent(context,AlarmPage.class);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent1.putExtra("id",id);
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

```
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        id=intent.getIntExtra("id",-1);
        Log.d("ID",id+"");
        Button dismiss=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("button","clicked");
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alarm.class);
                PendingIntent pi = (PendingIntent) PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, i, 0);
                alarmManager.cancel(pi);

            }
        });
```

After pressing the dismiss button I was expecting the Alarm to cancel, but nothing happens, the alarm just keeps ringing. My best guess was that it is somehow maybe creating a new pending intent but my request code is the same as my original pending intent.

Comment: what do you mean "it keeps ringing"? Please explain in more detail what is happening.